# Unable to show list once button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I am taking a beginners JavaScrpt class and I am having an issue with getting a button to show a list when I click on it.  I have reviewed my code but I just can't seem to see my issue.  Maybe another set of eyes will find my mistake.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

**Error Received:** TypeError: nikeDept.addEventListner is not a function.

This is the line where it says the error is located:  nikeDept.addEventListner("click", () => {

```js
let nike = {
  "location": "oregon", 
  "industry": "sportswear", 
  "departments": ["finance", "human resources", "operations"]
}

let nikeDept = document.getElementById("nikeDeptBtn");
nikeDept.addEventListner("click", () => {
  let myUl = document.querySelector("ul");
  for (let i = 0; i < nike.length; i++){
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = nike.departments[i];
    myUl.appendChild(li);
  }
})
```

Thanks
Carey

I thought I wrote it out correctly but obviously I didn't because it is not working.  I was expecting a list to appear once I clicked on the button.

Comment: It's `addEventListener` not `addEventListner`, just missing an `e`.

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much for seeing that!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the error you're receiving it says:
`TypeError: nikeDept.addEventListner is not a function.` The error shows you specifically how you spelled it.

You're missing an "e" between the "t" and "n" of "Listener" in `addEventListener`.

Comment: Instead of making an answer for questions with typos, you can flag it as needs improvement and has a typo (and maybe leave a comment). This is the preferred way.